# Logic for login in selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have implemented a logic in selenium.
The requirement is as below
Fetch User id and Password from excel sheet
If the User id exists it will go to login page and looks for element PageHeader_close application
If the User id does not exists
Test case will fail
But in my code for the id for which user does not exists its throwing element PageHeader_close application does not exists
Actually i want if the login is not successful it should fail there itself

Below is my code

```
@Test(dataProvider = "injectdataintovsslogin")
public void injectdataintowebsite(String username, String password) throws InterruptedException
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Eclipse\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://segotn11540.rds.scania.com/vss_connect_testr1/Login/Login.aspx");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='UserNameInputText']")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Brand']")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='CmdLogin']")).click();
    isuserloggedin();
}

public boolean isuserloggedin()
{
    boolean flag = true;
    if (!driver.findElements(By.id("Cancel")).isEmpty())
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("Cancel")).click();
    }
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("PageHeader_CloseApplication"))));
    if (!link.isDisplayed())
    {
        flag = false;
        System.out.println("User InCorrect");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("User Incorrect");
    }
    return flag;
}

@AfterMethod
public void teardown()
{
    driver.quit();
}

@DataProvider(name = "injectdataintovsslogin")
public Object[][] wordpressinjectprofile() throws Exception
{
    ReadExcelConfig file = new ReadExcelConfig("C:\\Code\\Test Data.xlsx");
    int rows = file.rowcount(0);
    Object[][] getdata = new Object[rows][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        getdata[i][0] = file.getdata(0, i, 0);
        getdata[i][1] = file.getdata(0, i, 1);
    }
    return getdata;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Jeff

I am pulling the user id's from excel sheet
I want to implement the logic as below

1.If the User exists
a)If cancel button is visible go to home page
b)Check for the element PageHeader_close application

2.)
If the user does not exists straight away fail the test case
Now for my code if the user does not exists it throws an exception since i have added find element
Because if the user does not exists there is no point finding the element

How can i modify the code

Comment: Any Expert Answers

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having problems with the control flow logic. `if` X `then` Y type stuff... I think you have some statements that need to go inside an `if` but I don't know which ones yet but I'm going to try to help. The problem is that I don't have enough information to know what's supposed to happen when and your code isn't labelled. First suggestion is to label your code. Put comments every so often explaining the code flow. For example, after an `if` and `else` put a short comment like `// customer successfully logged in`. It helps you (and others) remember what's going on in the UI and follow the flow.

I'm going to focus on your `isuserloggedin()` function because that's where I think the issue is. First off, follow Java conventions and use camel case and change the name to `isUserLoggedIn()`. See [Java conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). I put some comments and questions in the code below. Please have a look at them and answer the questions and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

How do I know if a user is logged in?

```
public boolean isUserLoggedIn()
{
    boolean flag = true;
    List<WebElement> cancelButton = driver.findElements(By.id("Cancel")); // fetch this once and use it twice, below
    if (!cancelButton.isEmpty())
    {
        // what does it mean when the Cancel button exists? User is logged in or not or ???
        cancelButton.get(0).click();
    }
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("PageHeader_CloseApplication"))));
    if (!link.isDisplayed()) // you waited for visibility above, you shouldn't need to check isDisplayed() here
    {
        // what does it mean if the link is missing? User isn't logged in or ?
        flag = false;
        // why is this sysout the same as the below? I'm guessing this is supposed to be "User is NOT logged in"?
        System.out.println("User InCorrect");
    }
    else
    {
        // why is this sysout the same as the above? I'm guessing this is supposed to be "User is logged in"?
        System.out.println("User Incorrect");
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff,
Thanks for your inputs.
Actually i changed the logic to assert the title
So the new logic is as below
Sign-In and get the title
If after login title matches login is successful
This actually worked for me

Comment: Since you are new to the site... if you found an answer helpful, you should upvote it. If an answer answered your question, you should accept it. It's a small reward to the people that spend time researching and answering question.